# Showing that a map $h:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ is an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, manifolds

**The Problem**

Let $h:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be a smooth map of the form 
$$ h(x,y,z)=(zy,yz,zx,ax^2+by^2).$$
Show that $h$ is an immersion for any $a,b\in \mathbb{R},a,b\neq 0,ab<0$.

**Attempt**

I have been trying to do this problem now for some time and have become quite frustrated. Below is my attempt.

We need to show that $dh(x):T_x S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ is injective for each $x\in \mathbb{S}^2$.

Notice that $h$ can be seen as the restriction of the smooth map $H:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4, \enspace H(x,y,z)=(xy,yz,zx,ax^2+by^2)$, and thus 
$$ dh(x)(v)=dH(x)(v)$$ 
for any $v\in T_x S^2$. Computing the Jacobian matrix of $H$, $J_x H$, we find that (where I have abused notation and set $x=(x,y,z)$):

$$J_x H=\begin{pmatrix}y & x& 0 \\ 0 & z & y \\ z& 0 & x \\ 2ax & 2by & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Let $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in T_xS^2$ such that $J_x H\cdot v=0$. If we can show that $v=0$ then we are done. Computing $J_x H \cdot v$ we end up with the following relations:
\begin{align}
yv_1 + xv_2&=0\quad (1)\\
 zv_2+yv_3&=0\quad (2) \\
zv_1+xv_3&=0\quad (3)\\
2axv_1+2byv_2&=0 \quad (4)
\end{align}

Furthermore since $T_x S^2=\{(v_1,v_2,v_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3:xv_1+yv_2+zv_3=0\}$
We get the relation $$xv_1+yv_2+zv_3=0\quad (5). $$

The idea at this point is to use relations $(1)-(5)$ together with the fact that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ to obtain the desired result. I have tried various things such as using $0=(1)^2+(2)^2+(3)^2$, but have just been left frustrated up until this point.

Answer (score 1):

(1) ==> y*v(1) = -x*v(2) ==> zy*v(1) = -zx*v(2)
(2) ==> z*v(2) = -y*v(3) ==> -zx*v(2) = xy*v(3)
Thus: yz*v(1) = yx*v(3). So if y = 0, then (1) gives: x*v(2) = 0, if x = 0 then z = 1 or - 1 either case (2) gives v(2) = 0, (5) gives -v(3) = 0 so v(3) = 0, and (3) gives 1*v(1) = 0 or -1*v(1) = 0 so v(1) = 0. So v = 0. Now if y is not 0, then z*v(1) = x*v(3). So (3) gives:
2z*v(1) = 0 = 2x*v(3). If z = 0, and x = 0, then y = 1 or -1 and use the above argument we get v = 0, if z or x is not 0, say z is not 0, then v(1) = 0, if x is not 0 then v(3) = 0, then (2) gives z*v(2) = 0 so v(2) = 0. So v = 0. If x = 0, then (4) gives 2by*v(2) = 0 so v(2) = 0, and (5) gives z*v(3) = 0 and this gives v(3) = 0 since z is not 0. So in all cases, you can deduce v = 0.

Comment: This seems to go through perfectly. My only concern is that I haven't used the condition ab<0 anywhere. Did I perhaps make a mistake somewhere? or maybe this condition is not necessary?

Comment: It seems that the condition ab < 0 is there to ensure that neither a nor b can be 0 so you can safely get v(2) = 0 from equation (4).

Comment: That's odd because it explicitly states before that $a\neq 0,b\neq 0$ as well as the condition $ab<0$

Comment: I might be missing this but I think you haven't included the case if $y\neq 0,z=0$ and $x\neq 0$, I think this case uses $ab<0$. you get $v_3=0$ but I then squared $(4)$ and used $ab<0$ in order to get $v_1=0$